# Socky with rails 2.3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket

I downloaded the rails 3.0.x socky demo app from : https://github.com/socky/socky-example. I remade the application in Rails 2.3.x. Now i have the following problem and i can't find any answers about it: When i run my application and i run the socky server and when i try to post a message this is the output i'm getting from the socky server:

```
D, [2011-01-07T13:01:31.250592 #23820] DEBUG -- : Connection(2159099260) terminated
D, [2011-01-07T13:01:36.425515 #23820] DEBUG -- : Connection(2159088740) incoming
D, [2011-01-07T13:01:36.426217 #23820] DEBUG -- : Connection(2159088740) sending data {"type":"message","body":"You are not authorized to post messages"}
D, [2011-01-07T13:01:36.426442 #23820] DEBUG -- : Connection(2159088740) terminated
```

How can i authorize myself / other users to post messages?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - Socky have it's own google group where it will be best to ask such a questions. Please see http://groups.google.com/group/socky-users.

And about your question: when you see "unauthorized" message then you probably didn't set "secret" variable in config, or this variable don't match the same variable in server and rails client(config.yml for socky-server and socky_hosts.yml for rails app)